# Azure Asp.net download files from DropBox using Dropbox.Api

Tags: asp.net, azure, dropbox-api

My asp.net web app requires downloading files from DropBox.
In DropBox, I created an app and have the API key and Auth Token, Secret, etc.
In my web app I have reference to Dropbox.Api and can create DropboxClient.

Like so:
    Dim myDBClient As New DropboxClient("my_token_auth")

What do I do next?  Does anyone have sample code.
I read I need to call async method to download such as code below.

But the code is not working.  Not failing either but does nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

```
Dim folder As String = "C:\Data"
Dim file2 As String = "myFile.txt"

Using response = myDBClient.Files.DownloadAsync("/" & folder & "/" & file2)
 Using fileStream = File.Create("C:\Data\myFile.txt")
      (response.GetContentAsStreamAsync()).CopyTo(fileStream))
 End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Await** to get the expected result.

**Demo code:**

```
 Dim myDbClient As New DropboxClient("auth token")
 Dim folder = "test"  'dropbox folder name
 Dim fileName = "1.txt" 'dropbox file name
 Dim response As IDownloadResponse(Of FileMetadata) = Await myDbClient.Files.DownloadAsync("/" + folder + "/" + fileName)
 Dim bytes = Await response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync()
 Using fileStream = Create("D:\tom\2.txt") ' local path

    fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

 End Using
```

**Update:**

Add the detail test steps:

1.Create dropbox app and generate the auth token.

[image]

2.Create the folder and upload the file to dropbox folder

[image]

3.Create an Asp.net  empty project and add a webform.aspx file named DropBoxApiTest.aspx and set it as start page.

4.To install Dropbox.Api, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package Dropbox.Api
```

5.Add the download button in the Webpage

```
 <asp:Button ID="_btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" />
```

6.Add the click event for the button and the following code.

```
 Protected Async Sub _btnDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _btnDownload.Click

        Dim token = "xaMln4bUnRAAAAAAAAAAIq...."
        Dim myDbClient As New DropboxClient(token)
        Dim folder = "test"  'dropbox folder name
        Dim fileName = "1.txt" 'dropbox file name
        Dim response As IDownloadResponse(Of FileMetadata) = Await myDbClient.Files.DownloadAsync("/" + folder + "/" + fileName)
        Dim bytes = Await response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync()
        Using fileStream = Create("D:\tom\download.txt") ' local path

            fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

        End Using

    End Sub
```

7.We also need to change aspx Async to true

8.Test it locally.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am getting closer. I added the await

Comment: But when it gets to the response line (downloadAsyn), it never comes back. Never ends so I have to kill in manually. and no error and file was not downloaded.  Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually I realized what was happening ... the code fails on the response line.  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"  what am I doing wrong here?  Thanks so much.

Comment: I have tested it on my side, it works correctly. You could just use the code I mentioned with your  dropbox folder name, file name and local path.

Comment: Hi Tom,  I'm still having trouble.  Can you tell me how you executed that demo code you sent me?  It should be in an async function, but how did you execute that async function.  Can it be done from a button click? Maybe there is where I'm hitting a snag.  Thanks alot.

Comment: Ok, getting closer Tom.  Now I execute your code (async),  but error occurs on the   DownloadAsync   error: "An error occurred while sending  the request."    Any ideas about this?   again, thank you.

Comment: I will add the detail test steps.

Comment: Tom,   Good news.  I got it to work!  Problem was I needed 'Full DropBox'  permissions on my App in DropBox.  Then it was tricky passing in the right path to DropBox from my app. Trial and error I got it.  THanks for your help.